# opening files in eog with output from awk

Tags: file, unix, redirect, awk, pipe

On unix system, I need to open the files that satisfy the following criterion:

`awk '{FS=",";if(($1>0.8)&&($2<0.2)){print NR-1"*png"}}' scindex_rscindex`

Whose output is

`287*png
 288*png`

I need to open these files in eog.

`awk '{FS=",";if(($1>0.8)&&($2<0.2)){print NR-1"*png"}}' scindex_rscindex |eog` doesnot work. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eog` does not read file names from standard input.  You are looking for

```
eog $(awk '{FS=",";if(($1>0.8)&&($2<0.2)){print NR-1"*png"}}' scindex_rscindex)
```

It is not clear whether or not you expect the output from the Awk script to be interpreted as shell wildcards, or as literal file names.  If indeed they are literal file names (with extremely poorly chosen names, given how they will complicate processing in the shell), you should quote them somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just use output of a *`command`* as argument for *`another`* do this:

```
another $(command)
```

Like:

```
eog $(awk '{FS=",";if(($1>0.8)&&($2<0.2)){print NR-1"*png"}}' scindex_rscindex)
```

If you use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), this could be enough. But under other [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), if you want `shell` doing wildcard development, you may have to:

```
eval "eog $(
  awk '{FS=",";if(($1>0.8)&&($2<0.2)){print NR-1"*png"}}')"
```

Comment: By "joker development" you mean "wildcard expansion", right?

Comment: In Bash, at least, the `eval` is not necessary.  Compare `echo $(echo '*')` which for me at least produces a directory listing of all files.

Comment: @tripleee You'r right, but as there is no indication that we are under [tag:bash], my answer is [tag:shell] based.